# Looking for text file search algorithm for very large projects in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, file-io, full-text-search

I'm trying to write a search algorithm in C# for a very large project (+700MB) and, due to my lack of experience, my code runs for over 30 hours before it ends/finds error. I'm not asking for anyone to do it for me, but to point me to an algorithm so I may study, learn and implement it.

**The project:** I have a text file with many keys and values (like a load file), let's call it **INI** file. I also have a huge project with many files in many folders. For each of these INI keys I have to:

1) Search the whole project (not the INI file) to make sure every key is being loaded. Each value will be loaded, individually, with a function named **LoadIniValue()**. If a value is not called in one of these functions, I will have to eventually remove it from the INI file.

2) In this **LoadIniValue()** function you also have the container the value will be stored in, passed as a parameter. Using that parameter as the new search key, is it used anywhere (except in the constructors or destructors) in the project? If the parameter is not used (evaluated, read, etc,) I will have to eventually remove it from the INI file.

The goal of this project is to have a clean INI file with no unused parameters.

I truly hope this will be considered a valid question and someone will be able to provide a clue.

Thanks so much to this community for helping me learn. You guys are really awesome!

Comment: I would use a database instead ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I thought of a hash table, but since the project is in constant change it would require a lot of time no?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more, please? If I understand correctly (and I VERY well may not), what's going on here is that you open each file in the project and see if it contains any of the keys in your .ini file. Then, whatever values are NOT found should be removed from the .ini file? Is that what your project is in essence? Also what do the files you're searching for look like and how big is each separate file you open? How do you go about searching within them now?

Comment: Maybe you're trying to solve the wrong problem? If your project accessed the INI file keys from one central place, using functions or properties to access the values, then your IDE could tell you whether any of those function were used or not (i.e. let the project take care of itself). Nonetheless, seeing the code you have for searching would be helpful.

Comment: Look into http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm

Comment: Suppose you had an unsorted phone directory and an unsorted list of phone calls, and you wanted to know who in the directory had not been called. Describe how you would solve that problem manually, ie, lists on paper.

Comment: You can solve this by going over the project only once. Store every call to `LoadIniValue` and then compare just the list of keys from your `INI`-file and stored list.

Comment: I'm just going to put in my 2-cents worth, then... Firstly, I wouldn't open up each file for each line in my .ini since that would be VERY slow. Rather, I'd load in the ini, then load in each file, search it for all the values, unload it and forget about it. Next, I would store (somewhere) which file had the matching value for each line in my .ini and its changed date. Then, if that file hasn't changed since my last search, I don't need to re-search for that key again. Another possibility for speed is multi-threading. As for search algorithms, I also like `Lucene` as posted in a solution.

Comment: @JohnBustos: That is the essence, yes. The project is a C++ .dsw with over 2000 files that have different sizes. All (if not most) are .cpp, .c and .h files, though the .h files can be skipped. LoadIniValues(INIfilePath, INIKey, INIValueContainer); we look for the INIKey (step 1) and, if it exists, we search for INIValueContainer in the whole project to confirm it's being used. After the first find we can stop, since we already know that it's being used.

Comment: @all: currently I run through all the files searching for LoadIniValues(), then I remove all the keys not being used. With the cleaner INI file I run through every file searching each and all of the project containers the INI values were stored in. I get that this is not the right way, but I had no other ideas. I don't have any of my code with me at the time, I'll try to provide some of it tomorrow.

Comment: @Cory: that's not the case. I have to make a C# project that will "clean" the INI file after searching all the specified (.cpp and .c) files and folders from a path for those keys that are 1)loaded 2)used

Answer (score 3):

You need an indexing agent.  Don't think you need to design it by yourself from scratch.
I would use **Lucene** to index these files and use its APIs to get the output.

Comment: Not sure that I can since the result of my work will be used by a corporation, but will definitelly look into it

Answer (score 0):

Following your description your code does something like this pseudo code:

```
foreach (entry in INI)
    foreach (file in ProjectFiles)
        Search for entry
```

Should this be the case you would search all your files for every key in the INI file. Most likely your files don’t change that much and we could expect that they don’t change at all while you are searching for the values.

You could then run only once through you files and build a list of all the used keys in the `LoadIniValue()` method. Next you could check if the entry in the INI file is in the used keys list. If not it can be removed. This would result in way less files that have to be read and with less IO it should run faster.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to do this in two passes.

In the first pass, search all of the source files for calls to `LoadIniValue()`. Store the name of the key being used and also the container. At the end of this pass you have a list of `key, container` pairs that are used in the code.

Match that against the keys in your INI file. Any key that exists in the INI but isn't in the `key, container` list is not being used. Any key that's in the list but not in the INI file is probably an error.

Now do a second pass through the source to determine which of the containers in the list are actually used outside of constructors and destructors.

This should execute pretty quickly. Probably in 10 minutes or less. You don't say how many files are in that 700 MB, but I suspect there are quite a few. If the files are small, your primary bottleneck is opening the files. With the method I suggest above, you only have to open each file twice. If I understand your question fully, your current implementation is opening every file for every INI key and for every container name.

If your current code works and you just want to speed it a bit, you might be able to just load all of the files into memory once, and then do all of your searching in memory. That would eliminate the overhead of opening and reading every file multiple times. I wouldn't be surprised to see that give you a 10x performance increase. It wouldn't be as fast as the two-pass solution I proposed above, but it might be good enough.